# Python XML string reassembly

Tags: python, xml, selenium, beautifulsoup

I've got following code for extracting lotto numbers from the web:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver

lottonumbers=[]

url="https://www.lotto.de/de/ergebnisse/lotto-6aus49/archiv.html"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

for ul in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "winning_numbers boxRow clearfix"}):
    n = ','.join(''.join(_ for _ in li if _.isdigit()) for li in ul.text.split())
    if n:
        print format(n)
```

Returns:`625262728475`

Should be:`6,25,26,27,28,47,5`

The commas are missing. Preferable each number should be written into the list `lottonumbers`.
Can anyone help out?

Comment: It would help if you made this code easily reproducible -- for example, nobody else reading this is going to have C://Users//Royskatt//Downloads//phantomjs-2.0.0-windows//bin//phantomjs.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I got it working with a hack (regular expressions).

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import re

url="https://www.lotto.de/de/ergebnisse/lotto-6aus49/archiv.html"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="C://Users//Royskatt//Downloads//phantomjs-2.0.0-windows//bin//phantomjs.exe")
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

lottonumbers = []

for ul in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "winning_numbers boxRow clearfix"}):
    for i in re.findall(r'(?<=zahl\([1-6]\)">)\d{1,2}|(?<="last">)\d', str(ul)):
        lottonumbers.append(i)

print lottonumbers
```

What I found out is, that using different webdrivers leads to small differences in the dynamically generated HTML. For example when using PhantomJS, I get the following result:
`['6', '25', '26', '27', '28', '47', '5']`, 

while webdriver.Firefox gives me

`['6', '25', '26', '27', '28', '47']`

MAYBE the different ouputs we experience while having the same code are caused by different versions of the webdrivers. For example the relevant lotto numbers in my case are written in a very long single line with no line break.

Answer (score 0):

You may probably assign an empty list of `lottonumbers` and append the **n** under another `for/loop`, like so:

```
# ... previous code ...
lottonumbers = []
for ul in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "winning_numbers boxRow clearfix"}):
    for li in ul.text.split():
        n = ''.join(_ for _ in li if _.isdigit())
        if n:
            lottonumbers.append(int(n))
print lottonumbers
[6, 25, 26, 27, 28, 47, 5]
```

Comment: i get [625262728475] 

(with webdriver.Firefox()). Running it on linux now, btw.

Comment: @royskatt, then just a little change on the code will do, I'm on my way home, will update later at night :)

Comment: @royskatt, that's odd, I'm using Firefox webdriver and the results are correct from the solution. Could you do a `print li.text` before `n` and see what results are?

Comment: gives me a AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'text'.
Btw, here the full code that returns the [625262728475]:  http://pastebin.com/nBB2V1at
Python 2.7.6, Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @royskatt, ahh sorry I was meant to say `print li`

Comment: 625262728475Super-zahl

Comment: @royskatt, that's strange, but in this case, you may try changing the `for/loop` of `for li in ...` to `for li in ul.li.text.split():` and see if it helps

Comment: That returns just the first number (6). Have you tried to execute the code that I pasted (http://pastebin.com/nBB2V1at). Does it also correctly seperate the numbers? If yes, then it's really strange because when I execute it,  that code on windows and linux returns [625262728475].

Comment: @royskatt, yes i run the code and it returns the list of numbers in lotto numbers correctly. it's *REALLY* strange. I will come back to you later, need to be in a meeting